# Android Gradle plugin requires Java 11 to run. You are currently using Java 1.8 - React Native

Tags: java, react-native, visual-studio-code

> Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.internal.application'. Android Gradle plugin requires Java 11 to run. You are currently using Java 1.8.

How can I change the version of Java used by the project? Download the corresponding version. I run the project from Visual Studio Code.

Add this code in "my-project/android/gradle.properties"

> org.gradle.java.home=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.14

But I get the following error:

> Value 'C:Program FilesJavajdk-11.0.14' given for org.gradle.java.home Gradle property is invalid (Java home supplied is invalid)

Answer (score 0):

there!

I was facing the same issue.

Just make sure you have your JAVA_HOME into yours enviroments variables, mine has the next path -> [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5AtRw.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the JDK version to compile your projects like this:

```
  "java.configuration.runtimes": [
    {
      "name": "JavaSE-17",
      "path": "C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\jdk-17.0.2",
      "default": true
    },
    {
      "name": "JavaSE-14",
      "path": "C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\jdk-14"
    }
  ],
```

You can refer to the [official docs](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/wiki/JDK-Requirements) for more details.